# flatten png on top of bitmap with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

I am trying to flatten a png with transparency over a bitmap with a solid colour.

so far i have this

```
    using (System.Drawing.Image backImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(layer1imagename))

    using (System.Drawing.Image frontImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + layer2))

    using (Image IMG1 = new Bitmap(251, 400))
    using (Graphics compositeGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(IMG1))
    {
        compositeGraphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        compositeGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(backImage, 0, 0);
        compositeGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(frontImage, 0, 0);
        compositeGraphics.Dispose();
        frontImage.Dispose();
        backImage.Dispose();
        IMG1.Save(layer1imagename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

However this turns removes the transparency on the top layer. How do i retain a transparent png on the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `using (Image IMG1 = new Bitmap(251, 400))` to `using (Image IMG1 = new Bitmap(251, 400, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))`.

For MSDN references see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx

EDIT - as per comment:

To draw the PNG you want you need to use a different [`CompositingMode` - `SourceOver` instead of `SourceCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingmode.aspx).

Comment: this seems to save the png but you cant see the background colour through it?